# SQL select from several tables and output to several tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have several tables of which most contain distinct ID columns and most have an additional column containing dates.
Now I need to retrieve all IDs with their corresponding dates from all tables.
Is there a way to output all IDs and dates from all tables at once and without creating duplicates ?

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table #t1
(
id int
)

insert into #t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
#t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: Wow, I am a total beginner and have no clue about DDL and DML.

I just want to know, if it is realistically possible with SQL to slect several collumns from several tables at once, if there is no common ID between the tables.

Comment: yes, you can check for cross join

Comment: So you want to [combine multiple queries](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm)? You said "most" tables have the ID and/or date columns so are you specifying the tables you want, or are you attempting to look across the schema and get any ID and date columns? And what does "output to several tables" mean?

Comment: I looked up with a previous querry which tables contain what, so I know the tables and names of the collums.
SQL seems to always output into a single table.
What I would like to have is:
Output from first table: <Optput table>
Output from second table: <Optput table> etc...
Doing a seperate request for eacht table would take too long.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45753314/edit) to explain what you mean, with sample data and output as has already been requested. Why would a separate request for each take longer? Maybe you're just looking for how to run a script containing several queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine multiple queries:

```
SELECT 'table_a' source, table_a_id id, creation_date FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_b' source, table_b_id id, creation_date FROM table_b
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_c' source, table_c_id id, creation_date FROM table_c;
```

If you need to remove duplicate rows, you can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, at the cost of some performance.

Comment: Tried that, but I only get back some of the collums.
E.g. the names of the date collums are all different and only one of them is showing up, if I querry with Union All.

Comment: You do get all the columns back. Each query must return the same number of columns, and the result set will use the column labels from the first query. In my example above, the second column will have the name `id` and contain the values of `table_a.table_a_id`, `table_b.table_b_id`, and `table_c.table_c_id`. If you want a particular column name, you can specify it; my example specifies the column name `id`.

Comment: Also, note how each row has a `source` column containing either `table_a`, `table_b`, or `table_c`, so that you can see which table each row came from.

Comment: OK, thank you markusk !
If I output all the date collums as the same name, I get what I need.

I then need to change back the name of the date collums afterwards, but that can be done clientside, because the table-name is known.

Comment: Also I forgot to tell you, that it only works, if I ommit the "ALL" after "UNION"
Can you change your answer to reflect that ?

Comment: Added a note about UNION vs UNION ALL.

Comment: Weird, because my querry only works without the "ALL"
The removal of the duplicates cannot be the only difference then.

Comment: How does your query fail when you include `ALL`? Do you get an error message? Are the results wrong?

Comment: It says one of my column names is a wrong identifier:

"CAPACITANCE_CHECK_TMP"."CHECK_DATE_CAPACITANCE_CHECK": invalid identifier.


If I remove the all the "ALL", it works and produces the output I need.

Also, why can't I format the text in this comment with even a simple line break ?

Comment: Strange. `UNION ALL` is supported by Oracle, according to https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.htm. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Regarding text formatting of comments: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work. There's some formatting available, but comments are intentionally short and limited. If you want to ask about a long section of code, you should probably post a new question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: I am using:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: And @Markusk, I was just really confused, that I could not even do a simple line break to make my comment more readable.

Comment: Oracle 11.2 also supports `UNION ALL`, as documented in [SQL Statements: SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm) and [The UNION \[ALL\], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries004.htm) in the Oracle 11.2 SQL Reference. So I can't really understand why you're getting an error. Could you please post your entire query that fails (or, if you like, a smaller version that exhibits the same problem)?

Comment: I really do not want to waste your time.
My problem has been solved by your suggestion to use UNION and my website has been working as it should ever since.